# Can I make a partial template that have readonly fields when used by show and not when used by edit and create?

Tags: grails, partials

I've partial templates that are used by the show, edit and create form.
In the show-form I don't want them editable, it can be confusing for the user.
Is there a simple solution for this otherwise I need a different template for the show-form or... why use a template then.

I've tied this and created 2 scripts, one that disables and one that enables.

Script 1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.elements').attr('readonly',true);
$('.elements').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Script 2.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.elements').attr('readonly',false);
$('.elements').prop('disabled',false);
});
```

Then I stored those scripts in assets\javascript.
It worked good in show but both edit and create went read-only too.

It seems like everything that is put in this directory is automatically used in each form, because even though I removed the call from the forms, it was working.

Here I show where I originally added the script-call:

```
    <asset:javascript src="myScript_1.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use jquery to disable/enable form fields.

`$('.elements').attr('readonly',true)` or  `$('.elements').prop('disabled',true)` the false to re-enable set the form elements that should do this to have a class called class='elements' to match that jquery call that will capture all form elements with that class

Comment: I failed here too. Look at my amendment.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add it as a comment but then it started to get long and complicated to follow.

1. why store it in assets ? 
   simply add a function block to the templates that need it

_template1.gsp

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setReadOnly('${someDefinition}')
function setReadOnly(value) {
  if (value==='READONLY') {
    $('.elements').attr('readonly',true).prop('disabled',true);
  }
}
})
</script>
```

If this function needs to be shared by a bunch of pages, you could add it to an assets / javascript file but rather than declare it in application.js call the js file `<asset:javascript` tags specificially on each page

and maybe a variable that you pass to template to say when it should be called

or put that above template1 as a master template and call in each of the other templates that needs the js file (So many options)

Now on the main controller doing action

```
def MyController {

    def view() {
      String mode='READONLY'
      render view: 'index', model:[instance:params,mode:mode]
    }
}
```

the in index.gsp

if js is there then it will pick up mode and set readonly for that controller action or pass that from one template to another, the controller does not have to define actual mode, the main master view page or index page could define mode too

Maybe you need to play/understand then implement you can't rush these things otherwise you will end up wasting time and rewriting

Just to ensure we are on the same page.

By default the application.js file in the javascript folder has a tree line enabled - this by default then reads in all js files. If you wish to manually call js in different places you will need to remove this line and declare each and every js file that you use like the other lines provided in that file.

So that is the price to pay (no more auto loading js files) until declared in application.js

But then most importantly as you have noticed these are global js functions and really nothing new should be going in there that hasn't got a `function something() { }` a function call.

They will then react when the actual function is called rather than how you had it which was open for call from any old page since it happened as documents opened regardless

Comment: That was good info, I'm afraid I'm not able to test this now, too much to do right now so I will return someday later. Thank's